# Printing multiple document types with different page settings

Tags: excel, vb.net, printing, ms-word, tiff

I have an automation script running whose output is various document types and printing those documents with various printer settings. I am printing to the same printer for all documents, so that's nice. I have three excel worksheets that need to be printed. These I am printing using the built-in "PrintOutEx" method. One onto a letter size paper and two to 11x17. Next, I have the script print a word document, which I am printing using the built-in "PrintOut" method. This is to be printed on an 11x17 paper but scaled so that two pages print side by side. Lastly, I have to print a multi-page tiff document which I am printing using a print handler. I am having a number of issues with this and I apologize if these are silly question and appreciate any help I can gather.

1. I am trying to keep the default printer the same as when I start the subroutines and that doesn't seem to be working using the PrinterSettings methods.
2. *About the default printer*: the default printer changes to the printer I want (doesn't change back at the end). The default printer is set to 11x17. If I change the default settings of the printer to 8.5x11 everything prints to 8.5x11.
3. The script seems to be ignoring the settings/pagesettings/setups that I am providing it with.
4. The word document print is not scaled to fit the paper and I have tried setting the paper size to 11x17 as well as 8.5x11 and scaling the print but that just looks really bad.
5. The first excel worksheet does not print to a letter size paper.
6. The second and third worksheets work okay (as long as the default printer settings are as desired; see point 2).
7. The multipage tiff document prints okay as long as the default printer's default settings are correct.

I am not a professional programmer so I apologize if the question has a simple answer or the code looks horrifying. I researched tons on this question and couldn't find a solution that worked. :( I stepped through the code line by line and there are no errors. I am attaching the code I have thus far.

Thanks!!!

```
Public Sub PrintSPIDPackage(SPID As String)

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim printerSettings As New Printing.PrinterSettings
    Dim curPrinter As String
    Dim engPrinter As String
    Dim purPrinter As String

    engPrinter = "engBLAH"
    purPrinter = "purBLAH"
    curPrinter = printerSettings.PrinterName

    Dim spidBBPath As String

    spidBBPath = ****REDACTED
    spidDrawingPackagePath = ***REDACTED*** 

    Dim eAPP As New Excel.Application
    Dim wB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim lRow As Integer
    Dim wAPP As New Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document

    wB = eAPP.Workbooks.Open(spidBBPath)

    wS = wB.Worksheets(selectedSheet & " OPs")
    wS.PageSetup.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperLetter 'I would think this causes the printer to printout to a letter size paper
    wS.PrintOutEx(ActivePrinter:=engPrinter)
    wS = wB.Worksheets(selectedSheet)
    lRow = wS.Range("A" & wS.Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row + 3
    rng = wS.Range("A1:I" & lRow)
    rng.PrintOutEx(ActivePrinter:=engPrinter) 'PRINT SHOULD BE AN 11x17
    wS = wB.Worksheets(selectedSheet & " MLB")
    wS.PrintOutEx(ActivePrinter:=engPrinter) 'PRINT SHOULD BE AN 11x17

    wB.Close(False)
    eAPP.Quit()
    Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wS)
    Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wB)
    Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(eAPP)

    If InStr(xPath, ".doc") <> 0 Then
        doc = wAPP.Documents.Open(xPath)
        wAPP.ActivePrinter = engPrinter
        doc.PageSetup.PaperSize = Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaperLetter ''''''print out should be 11x17 with two pages side by side
        wAPP.PrintOut(PrintZoomColumn:=2, PrintZoomRow:=1) ', PrintZoomPaperHeight:=2 * (11 * 1440), PrintZoomPaperWidth:=2 * (8.5 * 1440)) '''''AS you see I tried scaling...
        doc.Close(False)
        doc = Nothing
        wAPP.Quit()
        wAPP = Nothing
    End If

    Dim pDoc As New Printing.PrintDocument
    currPage = 0

    AddHandler pDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf pDocPage

    PrintDialog1.Document = pDoc
    pDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    pDoc.DocumentName = SPID & "-Drawing Package"
    pDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = engPrinter
    pDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    pDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 50
    pDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 50
    pDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 50
    pDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 50

    Dim ps As New Printing.PaperSize("Tabloid", 1700, 1100)
    ps.PaperName = Printing.PaperKind.Tabloid
    pDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps
    pDoc.Print()

    printerSettings.PrinterName = curPrinter 'this should reset the user's default printer to the original setting to before when this routine started??

    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox(Err.Description)

End Sub

Sub pDocPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

    Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(spidDrawingPackagePath)
    Dim pCount = img.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page)

    img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, currPage)

    Using stReader As IO.MemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream
        img.Save(stReader, ImageFormat.Bmp)
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = CType(Image.FromStream(stReader), Bitmap)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0)
        bmp.Dispose()
    End Using

    currPage += 1

    If currPage < pCount Then
        e.HasMorePages = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What issues are you having? Does it throw an error? It may help to comment out the `On Error GoTo errHandler` line, so it throws an error and you can click "Debug" to see what line it occurs on.

Comment: There is no error pop up, Mr. Batman Sir. 1. The user's default printer does not change back to the "curPrinter". The print follows the printers (manually assigned) default printer settings and preferences rather than the ones I assign programatically. E.G. If I change the default printer preferences to 8.5x11, the script prints everything to a 8.5x11 rather than the assigned paper size in the script. Also the word document scales with very large "margins" rather than fitting to the paper size This is the main problem because I need to print the documents with different settings.